# Функции перекодировки строк

Tags: java, кодировка, перекодировка

В переменную записан текст. Текст в кодировке utf-8/koi-8/windows-1251

Мне нужны функции, которые могут переводить их в друг друга.

Comment: "функции которые могут переводить их в друг друга"
Я так понимаю, это означает перекодирование из одной кодировки в дргую?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давным-давно скопипастил/написал и использую для перекодировки такую функцию:

```
public static void convert(
    String infile, //input file name, if null reads from console/stdin
    String outfile, //output file name, if null writes to console/stdout
    String from,   //encoding of input file (e.g. UTF-8/windows-1251, etc)
    String to)     //encoding of output file (e.g. UTF-8/windows-1251, etc)
        throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    // set up byte streams
    InputStream in;
    if(infile != null)
        in=new FileInputStream(infile);
    else
        in=System.in;
    OutputStream out;
    if(outfile != null)
        out=new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    else
        out=System.out;

    // Use default encoding if no encoding is specified.
    if(from == null) from=System.getProperty("file.encoding");
    if(to == null) to=System.getProperty("file.encoding");

    // Set up character stream
    Reader r=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, from));
    Writer w=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, to));

    // Copy characters from input to output.  The InputStreamReader
    // converts from the input encoding to Unicode,, and the OutputStreamWriter
    // converts from Unicode to the output encoding.  Characters that cannot be
    // represented in the output encoding are output as '?'
    char[] buffer=new char[4096];
    int len;
    while((len=r.read(buffer)) != -1)
        w.write(buffer, 0, len);
    r.close();
    w.flush();
    w.close();
}
```

Работает как часы - с успехом кодировал даже с китайского-писишного на UTF-8. Думаю ее несложно будет приспособить под декодирование строк

Answer (score 3):

```
Charset cset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
ByteBuffer buf = cset.encode(strOld);
byte[] b = buf.array();
String str = new String(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам, наверное, надо посмотреть класс `EncodingUtils` - думаю, там есть все нужные методы и функции.

Answer (score 0):

вот например перевода из 1251 в 1252:

```
var dt = new Java.Lang.String("some_string_in_1251");
Java.Lang.String win1252String = new Java.Lang.String(dt.GetBytes("windows-1252"), "windows-1251");
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?